# In SQLAlchemy, how can I prevent the reassignment of a child in a one-to-many relationship?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How can I dynamically prevent SQLAlchemy from reassigning a `many(Member)` to a different `one(Group)` if the member already belongs to a different group?

The semantics of the relationship are as follows:

- A `Group` may have *zero* or more `Members`
- A `Member` may belong to *zero* or *one* `Groups`
- Once assigned to a `Group`, a `Member` may not be assigned to a different `Group`, and attempting to do so should be a *no-op*

Example code:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlalchemy.orm as orm
from sqlalchemy import event


class Group:
    # Columns
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer(), primary_key=True)

    # Relationships
    members = orm.relationship('Member', back_populates='group')


class Member:
    # Columns
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer(), primary_key=True)

    # Relationships
    group_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer(), sa.ForeignKey('group.id'), nullable=True)
    group = orm.relationship('Group', back_populates='members')


@event.listens_for(Group.members, 'append', retval=True)
def _append_member(target, value, initiator):
    if value.mro is not None:
        msg = f'Warning: Member {value.id} already belongs to Group {value.group.id}. Cannot reassign'
        print(msg)

        # do something here to prevent the append
        return None
```

Example usage:

```py
list_of_lists = get_or_create_sorted_members()

for member_list in list_of_lists:
    group = Group()
    group.members.extend(member_list)
```

This works, expect that I can't figure out what to return from the event handler in order to signal to SQLAlchemy that no append should occur. Returning `None` produces an error during the next `session.flush()`. Returning any of the `orm.interfaces.EXT_XXX` constants produces immediate errors.

I can raise an exception, but that prevents subsequent calls from going through, and if I am adding to the relationship via `Group.members.extend(list_of_members)`, there is no opportunity to catch the exception so as to allow the other assignments to continue.

I could replace the direct relationship with a secondary link table that had a unique constraint `member.id`, but that seems overkill for a zero/one-to-many.

I have little control over the `get_or_create_sorted_members()` behavior.

Comment: @python_user Thanks. While replying to your question about why catching the exception wouldn't work, I tried reorganizing things a bit and it does actually work! Awsome! As to your other point, adding a unique constraint to the foreign key will turn the relationship into a *one-to-one*, since no two children (members in this example) could have the same parent (group).

Answer (score 0):

Raising an exception in the event callback function, then catching it in the caller works. When organized correctly, it will not prevent subsequent iterations.

```py
# Listener
# note that `retval=Ture` is no longer used, and the function does not return any data

@event.listens_for(Group.members, 'append')
def _append_member(target, value, initiator):
    if value.group_id is not None:
        raise ValueError(f'Member {value.id} already belongs to {value.group_id}')
```

```py
# caller

list_of_lists = get_or_create_sorted_members()

for member_list in list_of_lists:
    group = Group()
    try:
        group.members.extend(member_list)
    except ValueError as e:
        print(f'Warning: {e}')
```

With the above code, if 2 out of the 5 items in `member_list` have already been assigned to a group, then a warning will be printed, but the other items will continue to be assigned.